# Сould not record the request result in the file ( using curl )

Tags: magento2, download, curl

I am trying to get the file from a 3-d party server using \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl in my model. My aim is to record this file in the file on my server inside magento. The thing is the request passes successfully, I am getting the reply, but the file is created blank (zero byte file) and nothing is recorded in it. Here is the example of my code:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Write
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl
 * @var string $destination
 * @var string $source
*/
$newFile = $this->_directory->getDriver()->fileOpen($destination, "wb");
$this->_curl->addOption(CURLOPT_FILE, $newFile);
$this->_curl->write(\Zend_Http_Client::GET, $source);
$result = $this->_curl->read();
```

As a result i have the full reply in `$result` , the blank file in `$destination` .There are enough permissions i.e. even setting 777 on the directory and a current file, the result is not changing.

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 501 www-data 102 Apr  5 08:56 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 501 www-data 102 Apr  5 08:10 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 501 www-data   0 Apr  5 08:59 file_temp.gz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the file with `Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient` like this. `ZendClientFactory` will create instance of `Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClient` class:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory
 * @var string $url
 */
$client = $this->_httpClientFactory->create();
$client->setUri($url);
$client->setConfig(['maxredirects' => 0, 'timeout' => 30]);
$result = $client->request(\Zend_Http_Client::GET)->getBody();
```